# Индекс выделенного элемента в Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

С помощью какого метода корректно вернуть индекс выделенного элемента в Listbox? `listbox.curselection()` возвращает постоянно разные значения!

Comment: Если tkinter, то всё нормально. Возвращает последовательность выбранных. Если ничего не выбрано -- (). Пример в студию. И указывайте, какой пакет. А то их полно -- tk, gtk, wx, qt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так?

```
def Get(event):    
     print event.widget.curselection()

from Tkinter import *    
r = Tk()    
l = Listbox(r)    
l.insert(END, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')    
l.pack()    
l.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", Get)
r.mainloop()
```

Добавлено 09.02.12

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8:
def Get(event):    
    l = event.widget
    sel = l.curselection()
    if len(sel) == 1:
        s = l.get(sel[0])
        if s[0] == '-':
            l.selection_clear(sel[0])
        else:
            print s

from Tkinter import *    
r = Tk()    
l = Listbox(r)    
l.insert(END,  *('Открыть', 'Новый', '--------', 'Закрыть'))
for i in range(0, l.size()):
    if l.get(i)[0] == '-':
        l.itemconfig(i, foreground='gray', \
                selectforeground='gray', \
                selectbackground=l.itemcget(i, 'background'))
l.pack()    
l.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", Get)
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Работает! :) Спасибо огромное за помощь. Просто я программирую на КПК, а там, как известно не функционирует стандартное меню Tkinter. Вот и прошлось эмитировать его с помощью Listbox, срезая у окна титл. Кстати, что за событие такое "<<ListboxSelect>>"?

Comment: А Вы настырны. `man 3tk event`: `<<ListboxSelect>>
This is sent to a listbox when the set of selected item(s) in the listbox is updated.` Просто я немного на tcl/tk писал.

Comment: Нормально. А как сделать неактивный элемент в списке? Ибо в Ткинтер можно либо весь листбокс сделать статическим, либо никак :(

Comment: Неактивным -- это запрещенным (disabled)? Никак. Нет такого в listbox. Можно подкрасить другим цветом (метод .itemconfig), а запретить -- нет. Ну и при выборе элемента можно отрабатывать "невыборку"  А вот что касается "активного" (active) -- метод .activate

Comment: Ну, я так и сделал... Подкрасил "--------------". Думал, можно задизаблить...

Comment: А удалить не проще?

Comment: Мне нужна полная имитация меню ББ:

Открыть
Новый
--------
Закрыть
--------
Выход

"--------" - должен быть задизаблен :)

Comment: Добавлено в ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
Listbox.get("active")
```

tkinter

Comment: Увы. активный и выделенный -- это не одно и то же.

    #пример
    from Tkinter import *
    r = Tk()
    l = Listbox(r)
    l.insert(END, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
    l.pack()
    print (l.get('active'))
    print (l.curselection())`

Comment: Значит я чего то недопонял =)

Comment: curselection выдаёт последовательность индексов, get(ACTIVE) -- текст активного элемента. По описанию, если выделение одиночное, то они должны друг другу соответствовать, но get(ACTIVE) даёт элемент, даже если ни одного не выбрано. Кроме того у меня, в ubuntu, ctrl+<left> не меняет выбранные, но меняет индекс "активный".

Comment: get(ACTIVE) возвращает всегда предыдущий индекс! Первый раз - это нулевой индекс, чтобы не было выбрано, а после все, что было выбранно до этого.

Comment: @Xyanight не понял, почему так. Я привёл выше кусок кода. Что печатает print (l.get(ACTIVE))? (Если просто запустить скрипт)

Comment: e, ()
Вот и все.

    def Get(item):    
         print item  

    from Tkinter import *    
    r = Tk()    
    l = Listbox(r)    
    l.insert(END, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')    
    l.pack()    
    r.bind("<Button-1>", lambda X: Get(l.get('active')))    
    r.mainloop()

Сам попробуй и убедись :)))

Comment: Т.е. последний элемент, не выбрано ничего. () -- это curselection. И что неправильно ?

Comment: Все неправильно! Поюзай...

Comment: Уморист. bind на левую кнопку. А выбирать чем? И получается: первое нажатие кнопки -- отрабатывает процедура Get и печатает текущий активный элемент. Кроме того выбирается элемент под указателем мыши (и становится активным). А я-то думал, как это "предыдущий элемент" выдаётся...